# Which maven plugin can solve '[WARNING] 'artifactId' contains an expression but should be a constant'?

Tags: scala, maven, version-control, cross-build

Since maven 3 it is no longer recommended to include property variable in maven pom root artifactId section.

User will be prompted to remove it with this warning:

> [WARNING] 'artifactId' contains an expression but should be a constant.

This causes severe incompatibility problem with cross-built scala project, which should always include _${scala.binary.version} in their artifactId. (the exact version interpolation of the published artifact can be handled by flatten-maven-plugin, not a big deal)

I've tried several possible replacement to overcome this, including:

1. override build/finalName
2. override build/plugins/plugin/maven-jar-plugin/configuration/finalName
3. override build/plugins/plugin/maven-install-plugin/configuration/artifactId.

Turns out that none of them works. What is the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Can you give an example how such pom file looks like?

Comment: @khmarbaise example added